# Amplify authentication user data + graphql API

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm developing an app that should have a schedule date to users. Let's say that it's a soccer match.

So it would have:

- id
- full date
- players

The "players" itself are all users that must authenticate using the standard AWS Amplify authentication and of course are enrolled in the game.
I want to be able to retrieve all the players (email, username) who is in a match.
I am about to do the graphql API model to the match entity. How am I suppose to map the one-to-many players from the AWS Authentication?

Should I just map the fields that I want (email, username) or is there any kind of direct relationship that I can use to retrieve the user object? like search by an id.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you create a "database user" and save the ID to Cognito as `custom user attributes`, which allows you to fetch the user information from there at a later point:

```
// On Signup
const { data } = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, {input: user}));
await Auth.updateUserAttributes(cognitoUser, {'custom:dbuserid': data.createUser.id});

// On Signin
const cognitoUser = await Auth.signIn({ username: rusername, password: rpassword })
const { data } = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUser, {id: cognitoUser.attributes["custom:dbuserid"] }));
```

Or you save all your user information to Cognito as `custom user attributes`, but I believe there is a max of 50, which could be a limit for you.